# Android Retrofit - How to read Response From Server

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm working on android project I received JSON Object

```
{"t":"Terminal1.mobileWalletPassword","v":"0000"},{"t":"Terminal1.PasswordAdjust","v":"0000"},{"t":"Terminal1.PasswordAuth","v":"0000"}
    {"t":"Terminal1.Acquirer4.Issuer1.BinList1.BinRange61.txtMatchLength","v":"00"},{"t":"Terminal1.Acquirer4.Issuer1.BinList1.BinRange61.txtName","v":"CUP_620220"}
```

in my project there are classes like

```
    public class Terminal {
private String PasswordAuth="";
private String mobileWalletPassword
....
}
```

and I have

```
    public class Acquirer{
.....
    }
```

and I have

```
    public class Issuer{
...
    }
```

How I can handle this response

Comment: But the attributes named are `t` and `v` . It seem doesn't related with the model classes

Comment: Please set the valid Json!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send the full output format of the api .because your file is not valid ! ?

Answer (score 0):

Your response not possible to cast to your model.